# why i'm getting errors in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

i'm new in nestjs, i created a new app and i start to write a new module but i'm getting errors, i'm sure of syntax, but i don't know why i'm getting errors.

i change the version of typescript(4.9) but still not working.

the code:
users/users.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

users/users.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService{
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

users/users.controller.ts:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService} from './users.service';

@Controller()
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: UsersService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "server_2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

[the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnOzt.png)

i change the version of typescript(4.9) but still not working.

Comment: Seeing as this is on every line, iit's most likely an eslint "error" due to the line ending, but the screenshot isn't helpful beyond that. Please paste the error text in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply line-break errors. At the bottom-right corner of VS Code, change **CRLF** to **LF** and those errors won't be displayed anymore.

Comment: thanks bro. it was CRLF and i changed it to LF, it's working.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept it as answer if that solved your problem permanently.

Comment: sure i will do :)